# Example on topologies in Munkres

Tags: general-topology

Given a set $X = \{a,b,c\}$, the following image depicts two subsets of $P(X)$ that are not topologies (image from Topology by Munkres).

[image: Munkres Topology Example]

The first set (on the left in figure $12.2$) $X_1 = \{ \emptyset, X, \{a\},\{b\} \}$ and the second set (on right) $X_2 = \{\emptyset, X, \{a,b\},\{b,c\} \}$. Why aren't $X_1$ and $X_2$ topologies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\{a\}\cup\{b\} \not\in\ X_1$ and $\{a,b\}\cap\{b,c\}\not\in X_2$.